# JS Tree search fails

Tags: javascript

I have Javascript tree structure

```
const tree = [
    {id: 120 , children:[]},
    {id: 110 , children:[
        {id: 12 , children:[
            {id: 3 , children:[]},
            {id: 4 , children:[]}
        ]}
    ]},
    {id: 10 , children:[
        {id: 13 , children:[]}
    ]}
    ]
```

and i have this function to find the parent of given node

```
const _findParent = (tree, component, _parent) => {
    let parent = null
    // iterate
    tree.forEach(node => {
        if(node.id === component.id){
            return _parent
        }

        parent = node. children ? _findParent(node.children, component, node) : parent

    })
    return parent
}
```

but it returns null, I cant find where i miss the parent object.

Comment: What do you see when you debug it? This is just something you have to work through using the powerful debugger built into your browser / available in your IDE to step through the code statement by statement, inspecting variables, etc., not a question that's appropriate for SO. *(not my dv; it is my close vote)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you check the `children`, but your `children` is always an array which is a truthy value. In this case, you could check if `children` is an array.

The use of [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) does not work with a return value for using outside of the callback.

I suggest to use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), which allows an early exit, which is necessary if a node is found.

Then I suggest to use a second variable for getting a nested result and if truthy, then assign to `parent` for return and exit the iteration.

```js
const _findParent = (tree, component, _parent) => {
    let parent;
    tree.some(node => {
        var temp;
        if (node.id === component.id) {
            parent = _parent;
            return true;
        }
        temp = Array.isArray(node.children) && _findParent(node.children, component, node);
        if (temp) {
            parent = temp;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return parent;
}

const tree = [{ id: 120, children: [] }, { id: 110, children: [{ id: 12, children: [{ id: 3, children: [] }, { id: 4, children: [] }] }] }, { id: 10, children: [{ id: 13, children: [] }] }];

console.log(_findParent(tree, { id: 4 }));
console.log(_findParent(tree, { id: 42 }));
```